# Создание пустых каталогов в Windows

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

Стоит задача написать PL/SQL процедуру, которая будет создавать пустую папку по указанному пути.

Я знаю что для этого можно использовать класс написанный на Java, а так же выдавать права пользователю, на доступ к этой папке.

Пишу вот такой класс:

```
public class Create_Folder
{
 public static void create( java.lang.String  patch )
 {
 String sLogText;
 try
 {
  File dir = new File(patch);
  boolean created = dir.mkdir();
  if(created)
  {
   sLogText = "Каталог успешно создан ) "+dir.getAbsolutePath() ;
   #sql{ INSERT INTO PARUS.DIAGNOSTIC_LOG(NUM_LOG, TEXT_LOG) VALUES (2,:sLogText) };  
   #sql { COMMIT };
  }
  else
  {
   sLogText = "Каталог не создан (" ;
   #sql{ INSERT INTO PARUS.DIAGNOSTIC_LOG(NUM_LOG, TEXT_LOG) VALUES (2,:sLogText) };  
   #sql { COMMIT };
  }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   ex.printStackTrace();
}     }    }
```

Код для процедуры оболочки:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Create_folder(sPatch   in varchar2)
 AS LANGUAGE JAVA  NAME 'Create_Folder.create(java.lang.String)';
```

Код для процедуры PL/SQL:

```
create or replace procedure P_CREATE_FOLDER
(
 sPATCH    in varchar2
)
  as
 begin
   delete diagnostic_log;
   dbms_java.grant_permission('USER','SYS:java.io.FilePermission','sPATCH', 'read,write' );
   Create_folder(sPATCH);
 end;
```

Планирую создавать папки по пути `F:\\...`. В лог таблицу иногда сообщается, что успешно создан каталог, иногда то, что не создан. После сообщения об успешном создании каталога по указанному пути ничего не создано.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Попытался создавать файлы методом createNewFile() , так же сообщается что файл создан, но его нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось довольно просто, файлы и папки создавали на серверной машине, где располагается БД. Приведенный мной код рабочий.

Answer (score 2):

Причина понятна, код выполняется в процесе на сервере, создать каталоги он может только в файловой системе сервера.

Очевидно, что стояла задача создать каталоги в файловой системе клиента. Для этого надо вернуть команду со списком каталогов созданную в PL/SQL процедуре / функции и выполнить её в клиенте.

Например, в SQL*Plus или SQL Developer так будет работать:

```
set autoprint on 
var rc refcursor
col cmd new_value cmd noprint 
begin
    open :rc for
        with data (path) as (
            select 'D:\test0'       from dual union all
            select 'D:\test0\test1' from dual union all
            select 'D:\test0\test2' from dual
        ) 
    select 'md '||listagg (path, ' ') cmd from data;
end;
/
host &cmd

host tree d:/test0
d:/test0
|-- test1
`-- test2
```